# GGplot + Shiny changing a line color based off slope of line

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am trying to have multiple lines each of which changes between red and green depending on its slope. So if one changes from positive to negative it will change from green to red at that point. I have tried splitting the data so that red lines are formed between negative points and vice versa for green, but I encounter a problem. When a line goes from positive to negative back to positive; it is red. This is because red needs to know all points in that sequence to build the red lines but I want to avoid it connecting the positive slope line with red. An example of this is the bottom line in the below graph at Mar 15 [image] I don't know if it makes a difference but I am using shiny whit ggplot.

```
output$pen_performance_graphs <- renderPlotly({
    #subsets data to date range selected
    #five_year_disp <-subset(five_year_weekly, as.Date(Date)>=input$pen_dates[1]&date<=input$pen_dates[2])
    five_year_disp <- five_year_weekly[five_year_weekly$Date >= input$pen_dates[1],]
    five_year_disp <- five_year_disp[five_year_disp$Date <= input$pen_dates[2],]
    
    ggp <- ggplot(five_year_disp, aes(x = as.Date(Date), y = Yeild, 
                                      label = Date,
                                      label2 = Animal_ID,
                                      label3 = Precent_Change,
                                      label4 = Yeild,
                                      label5 = Treatment,
                                      group = Animal_ID,xmin = as.Date(input$pen_dates[1], "%Y-%m-%d"), 
                                      xmax = as.Date(input$pen_dates[2],  "%Y-%m-%d"),)) +
      geom_line() +
#GREEN LINES
      geom_line(data=five_year_disp, aes(x=as.Date(Date), y=posY, col="green")) +
#RED LINES
      geom_line(data=five_year_disp, aes(x=as.Date(Date), y=negY, col="red")) +
      scale_color_identity() +
      geom_point() +
      labs(x = "Date", y = "Milk Yeild (LBS)")
    #ggp <- ggp + scale_x_date(limits = as.Date(c(input$pen_dates[1], input$pen_dates[2])), date_breaks = "month")
    p <- ggplotly(ggp, tooltip = c("label", "label2", "label3", "label4", "label5"))
    p
    
  })
```

```
dput(five_year_disp)
structure(list(Animal_ID = c(578L, 578L, 578L, 578L, 578L, 578L, 
578L, 578L, 578L, 578L, 578L, 578L, 578L, 579L, 579L, 579L, 579L, 
579L, 579L, 579L, 579L, 579L, 579L, 579L, 579L, 579L, 618L, 618L, 
618L, 618L, 618L, 618L, 618L, 618L, 618L, 618L, 618L, 618L, 618L, 
5082L, 5082L, 5082L, 5082L, 5082L, 5082L, 5082L, 5082L, 5082L, 
5082L, 5082L, 5082L, 5082L, 5451L, 5451L, 5451L, 5451L, 5451L, 
5451L, 5451L, 5451L, 5451L, 5451L, 5451L, 5451L, 5451L, 5570L, 
5570L, 5570L, 5570L, 5570L, 5570L, 5570L, 5570L, 5570L, 5570L, 
5570L, 5570L, 5570L, 5836L, 5836L, 5836L, 5836L, 5836L, 5836L, 
5836L, 5836L, 5836L, 5836L, 5836L, 5836L, 5836L, 5842L, 5842L, 
5842L, 5842L, 5842L, 5842L, 5842L, 5842L, 5842L, 5842L, 5842L, 
5842L, 5842L, 5868L, 5868L, 5868L, 5868L, 5868L, 5868L, 5868L, 
5868L, 5868L, 5868L, 5868L, 5868L, 5868L, 5883L, 5883L, 5883L, 
5883L, 5883L, 5883L, 5883L, 5883L, 5883L, 5883L, 5883L, 5883L, 
5883L), Date = c("2021/02/08", "2021/02/13", "2021/02/20", "2021/02/27", 
"2021/03/01", "2021/03/08", "2021/03/13", "2021/03/20", "2021/03/27", 
"2021/04/01", "2021/04/08", "2021/04/13", "2021/04/20", "2021/02/08", 
"2021/02/13", "2021/02/20", "2021/02/27", "2021/03/01", "2021/03/08", 
"2021/03/13", "2021/03/20", "2021/03/27", "2021/04/01", "2021/04/08", 
"2021/04/13", "2021/04/20", "2021/02/08", "2021/02/13", "2021/02/20", 
"2021/02/27", "2021/03/01", "2021/03/08", "2021/03/13", "2021/03/20", 
"2021/03/27", "2021/04/01", "2021/04/08", "2021/04/13", "2021/04/20", 
"2021/02/08", "2021/02/13", "2021/02/20", "2021/02/27", "2021/03/01", 
"2021/03/08", "2021/03/13", "2021/03/20", "2021/03/27", "2021/04/01", 
"2021/04/08", "2021/04/13", "2021/04/20", "2021/02/08", "2021/02/13", 
"2021/02/20", "2021/02/27", "2021/03/01", "2021/03/08", "2021/03/13", 
"2021/03/20", "2021/03/27", "2021/04/01", "2021/04/08", "2021/04/13", 
"2021/04/20", "2021/02/08", "2021/02/13", "2021/02/20", "2021/02/27", 
"2021/03/01", "2021/03/08", "2021/03/13", "2021/03/20", "2021/03/27", 
"2021/04/01", "2021/04/08", "2021/04/13", "2021/04/20", "2021/02/08", 
"2021/02/13", "2021/02/20", "2021/02/27", "2021/03/01", "2021/03/08", 
"2021/03/13", "2021/03/20", "2021/03/27", "2021/04/01", "2021/04/08", 
"2021/04/13", "2021/04/20", "2021/02/08", "2021/02/13", "2021/02/20", 
"2021/02/27", "2021/03/01", "2021/03/08", "2021/03/13", "2021/03/20", 
"2021/03/27", "2021/04/01", "2021/04/08", "2021/04/13", "2021/04/20", 
"2021/02/08", "2021/02/13", "2021/02/20", "2021/02/27", "2021/03/01", 
"2021/03/08", "2021/03/13", "2021/03/20", "2021/03/27", "2021/04/01", 
"2021/04/08", "2021/04/13", "2021/04/20", "2021/02/08", "2021/02/13", 
"2021/02/20", "2021/02/27", "2021/03/01", "2021/03/08", "2021/03/13", 
"2021/03/20", "2021/03/27", "2021/04/01", "2021/04/08", "2021/04/13", 
"2021/04/20"), Yeild_gr = c(50670, 46065, 40101, 32613, 37695, 
37036, 30634, 33787, 31460, 30826, 26050, 27395, 28957, 38375, 
40061, 34028, 25966, 28609, 33850, 27921, 31511, 30946, 28963, 
26031, 27421, 27754, 49306, 51508, 44800, 37900, 41330, 44519, 
38556, 41680, 43477, 40167, 32131, 39124, 40348, 50872, 49346, 
42075, 45195, 44415, 46700, 44372, 44211, 39444, 37177, 39067, 
36270, 37110, 52265, 45753, 42932, 40839, 39943, 43049, 42969, 
44352, 43141, 35598, 30473, 29328, 29415, 42137, 39911, 33229, 
28658, 29314, 42391, 31544, 35591, 32331, 31842, 21259, 27222, 
21272, 33986, 36264, 28851, 34661, 32127, 32005, 27759, 29025, 
27663, 26708, 26692, 26025, 24856, 32255, 30794, 29464, 32200, 
32139, 26482, 24468, 26563, 25800, 24214, 21352, 23367, 20130, 
38088, 39296, 35180, 35936, 39282, 37509, 38335, 33096, 38771, 
36884, 34456, 29630, 34145, 44728, 51297, 39168, 45407, 50389, 
45554, 47758, 48574, 47675, 34608, 43766, 37066, 40068), Conductivity = c(9.8, 
9.6, 10.4, 10.8, 10.4, 10, 10.4, 10.2, 10.2, 10.6, 10.1, 10.5, 
10, 9.9, 9.6, 11.1, 9.9, 9.9, 10.1, 10.5, 9.8, 10.3, 11.6, 10.8, 
12.1, 10.7, 8.6, 8.8, 8.8, 9.1, 10.2, 8.9, 9, 8.8, 8.8, 9.8, 
8.4, 10.1, 8.8, 10, 9.7, 9.7, 10.1, 10.1, 9.9, 9.7, 10, 10.2, 
9.8, 9.8, 10.2, 9.9, 8.5, 8.9, 8.9, 9, 8.8, 8.7, 8.9, 8.8, 8.6, 
8.5, 8.8, 8.6, 8.8, 10.1, 10.7, 10.8, 11.4, 10.5, 10.1, 10.7, 
10.3, 10.2, 10.2, 10.5, 11.1, 11.4, 8.4, 9, 9, 8.6, 9.2, 8.6, 
9, 9.2, 8.7, 9.6, 9.4, 9.3, 9.3, 9.9, 8.4, 10.5, 11.2, 9.7, 8.5, 
9.6, 10.3, 8.9, 10.3, 10.6, 10.5, 9.9, 8.7, 8.7, 9.1, 9.4, 9.1, 
8.6, 8.9, 8.9, 9.1, 9.2, 9.3, 9.6, 9.1, 10.3, 9.6, 10.3, 10.6, 
10.5, 10.4, 10.8, 9.9, 9.3, 10, 10, 10.6, 10.3), FatPct = c(4.7, 
4.4, 5.1, 4.5, 5.1, 4.6, 5, 5, 5.2, 4.6, 4.8, 4.8, 4.9, 4.2, 
4.4, 4.5, 4.4, 4.7, 4.8, 4.8, 4.6, 3.9, 5.3, 5.2, 5.1, 4.3, 4.1, 
3.9, 3.8, 4.2, 4, 4.5, 4.2, 4, 4.6, 4.2, 4.8, 4.1, 4.2, 4.2, 
3.6, 4.2, 4, 3.6, 3.6, 3.4, 3.5, 3.9, 3.9, 4.2, 4.4, 4.1, 3.7, 
4.7, 5.2, 4.6, 4.3, 5.1, 3.8, 4, 4.2, 6, 5.4, 5.4, 5.4, 3.2, 
4.8, 3.5, 3.7, 5.1, 3.9, 4.6, 3.5, 3.7, 4, 3.9, 4.1, 3.7, 3.9, 
3.9, 4.3, 4.1, 3.9, 4.9, 4.1, 4.1, 3.9, 4.1, 4.2, 4.7, 3.8, 3.6, 
4.3, 4.1, 3.7, 3.4, 3.9, 3.4, 4.6, 3.6, 3.5, 4, 3.5, 4.2, 5.2, 
5.7, 5.8, 4.9, 5.5, 5.5, 4.5, 5.4, 6, 4.5, 5.6, 6.5, 4.5, 4.2, 
4, 3.8, 4.7, 4.3, 4, 4.9, 3.6, 4, 4.3, 4.2, 4.3, 3.9), ProPct = c(3, 
3.1, 3.8, 4, 3.2, 3.9, 2.8, 3.2, 3.3, 3.1, 4, 3, 3.4, 4.3, 4.1, 
3.7, 4.4, 3.5, 2.7, 3.2, 3.9, 3.8, 2.9, 2.9, 3, 3.2, 3.5, 3.7, 
3.2, 3.6, 3.6, 3.1, 3.9, 3.4, 2.8, 3.9, 4.2, 4, 4.2, 3.4, 4.7, 
2.8, 3.8, 3.5, 4.4, 4.2, 4.1, 3.5, 4.3, 3.9, 3.6, 3.7, 4.2, 4.6, 
3.6, 3.1, 3.7, 3.4, 4.1, 4.4, 4.1, 3.6, 3.4, 3.9, 3.4, 4.3, 4, 
4.7, 4.5, 4, 3.9, 4.1, 4.1, 4.5, 3.7, 4.4, 4, 4.3, 3.7, 3.8, 
3.2, 2.9, 3.8, 3.5, 3.6, 4.2, 3.7, 3.8, 3, 3.3, 3.8, 4.1, 3.1, 
3.9, 4.3, 4.1, 3.6, 4.2, 3.4, 3.1, 4, 4.1, 3.4, 3.3, 3.7, 4.9, 
4.4, 3.7, 4.3, 2.9, 3.3, 4, 2.7, 4.3, 4.4, 4, 4.3, 3.6, 3.3, 
3.7, 2.7, 3.3, 2.5, 3.1, 3.1, 3.2, 4.3, 3.5, 2.6, 3), Yeild = c(111.71, 
101.56, 88.41, 71.9, 83.1, 81.65, 67.54, 74.49, 69.36, 67.96, 
57.43, 60.4, 63.84, 84.6, 88.32, 75.02, 57.25, 63.07, 74.63, 
61.56, 69.47, 68.22, 63.85, 57.39, 60.45, 61.19, 108.7, 113.56, 
98.77, 83.56, 91.12, 98.15, 85, 91.89, 95.85, 88.55, 70.84, 86.25, 
88.95, 112.15, 108.79, 92.76, 99.64, 97.92, 102.96, 97.82, 97.47, 
86.96, 81.96, 86.13, 79.96, 81.81, 115.22, 100.87, 94.65, 90.03, 
88.06, 94.91, 94.73, 97.78, 95.11, 78.48, 67.18, 64.66, 64.85, 
92.9, 87.99, 73.26, 63.18, 64.63, 93.46, 69.54, 78.46, 71.28, 
70.2, 46.87, 60.01, 46.9, 74.93, 79.95, 63.61, 76.41, 70.83, 
70.56, 61.2, 63.99, 60.99, 58.88, 58.85, 57.38, 54.8, 71.11, 
67.89, 64.96, 70.99, 70.85, 58.38, 53.94, 58.56, 56.88, 53.38, 
47.07, 51.52, 44.38, 83.97, 86.63, 77.56, 79.23, 86.6, 82.69, 
84.51, 72.96, 85.48, 81.32, 75.96, 65.32, 75.28, 98.61, 113.09, 
86.35, 100.11, 111.09, 100.43, 105.29, 107.09, 105.11, 76.3, 
96.49, 81.72, 88.33), Treatment = c(78, 73, 66, 59, 57, 50, 45, 
38, 31, 26, 19, 14, 7, 78, 73, 66, 59, 57, 50, 45, 38, 31, 26, 
19, 14, 7, 78, 73, 66, 59, 57, 50, 45, 38, 31, 26, 19, 14, 7, 
78, 73, 66, 59, 57, 50, 45, 38, 31, 26, 19, 14, 7, 78, 73, 66, 
59, 57, 50, 45, 38, 31, 26, 19, 14, 7, 78, 73, 66, 59, 57, 50, 
45, 38, 31, 26, 19, 14, 7, 78, 73, 66, 59, 57, 50, 45, 38, 31, 
26, 19, 14, 7, 78, 73, 66, 59, 57, 50, 45, 38, 31, 26, 19, 14, 
7, 78, 73, 66, 59, 57, 50, 45, 38, 31, 26, 19, 14, 7, 78, 73, 
66, 59, 57, 50, 45, 38, 31, 26, 19, 14, 7), Precent_Change = c("12.6", 
"-9.1", "-12.9", "-18.7", "15.6", "-1.7", "-17.3", "10.3", "-6.9", 
"-2.0", "-15.5", "5.2", "5.7", "-0.2", "4.4", "-15.1", "-23.7", 
"10.2", "18.3", "-17.5", "12.8", "-1.8", "-6.4", "-10.1", "5.3", 
"1.2", "-9.4", "4.5", "-13.0", "-15.4", "9.0", "7.7", "-13.4", 
"8.1", "4.3", "-7.6", "-20.0", "21.8", "3.1", "-4.0", "-3.0", 
"-14.7", "7.4", "-1.7", "5.1", "-5.0", "-0.4", "-10.8", "-5.7", 
"5.1", "-7.2", "2.3", "4.7", "-12.5", "-6.2", "-4.9", "-2.2", 
"7.8", "-0.2", "3.2", "-2.7", "-17.5", "-14.4", "-3.8", "0.3", 
"14.7", "-5.3", "-16.7", "-13.8", "2.3", "44.6", "-25.6", "12.8", 
"-9.2", "-1.5", "-33.2", "28.0", "-21.8", "3.6", "6.7", "-20.4", 
"20.1", "-7.3", "-0.4", "-13.3", "4.6", "-4.7", "-3.5", "-0.1", 
"-2.5", "-4.5", "4.1", "-4.5", "-4.3", "9.3", "-0.2", "-17.6", 
"-7.6", "8.6", "-2.9", "-6.2", "-11.8", "9.5", "-13.9", "4.0", 
"3.2", "-10.5", "2.2", "9.3", "-4.5", "2.2", "-13.7", "17.2", 
"-4.9", "-6.6", "-14.0", "15.2", "-6.2", "14.7", "-23.6", "15.9", 
"11.0", "-9.6", "4.8", "1.7", "-1.8", "-27.4", "26.5", "-15.3", 
"8.1"), posY = c(111.71, NA, NA, 71.9, 83.1, NA, 67.54, 74.49, 
NA, NA, 57.43, 60.4, 63.84, 84.6, 88.32, NA, 57.25, 63.07, 74.63, 
61.56, 69.47, NA, NA, 57.39, 60.45, 61.19, 108.7, 113.56, NA, 
83.56, 91.12, 98.15, 85, 91.89, 95.85, NA, 70.84, 86.25, 88.95, 
NA, NA, 92.76, 99.64, 97.92, 102.96, NA, NA, NA, 81.96, 86.13, 
79.96, 81.81, 115.22, NA, NA, NA, 88.06, 94.91, 94.73, 97.78, 
NA, NA, NA, 64.66, 64.85, 92.9, NA, NA, 63.18, 64.63, 93.46, 
69.54, 78.46, NA, NA, 46.87, 60.01, 46.9, 74.93, 79.95, 63.61, 
76.41, NA, NA, 61.2, 63.99, NA, NA, NA, NA, 54.8, 71.11, NA, 
64.96, 70.99, NA, NA, 53.94, 58.56, NA, NA, 47.07, 51.52, 44.38, 
83.97, 86.63, 77.56, 79.23, 86.6, 82.69, 84.51, 72.96, 85.48, 
NA, NA, 65.32, 75.28, 98.61, 113.09, 86.35, 100.11, 111.09, 100.43, 
105.29, 107.09, NA, 76.3, 96.49, 81.72, 88.33), negY = c(111.71, 
101.56, 88.41, 71.9, 83.1, 81.65, 67.54, 74.49, 69.36, 67.96, 
57.43, NA, NA, 84.6, 88.32, 75.02, 57.25, NA, 74.63, 61.56, 69.47, 
68.22, 63.85, 57.39, NA, NA, 108.7, 113.56, 98.77, 83.56, NA, 
98.15, 85, NA, 95.85, 88.55, 70.84, NA, NA, 112.15, 108.79, 92.76, 
99.64, 97.92, 102.96, 97.82, 97.47, 86.96, 81.96, 86.13, 79.96, 
NA, 115.22, 100.87, 94.65, 90.03, 88.06, 94.91, 94.73, 97.78, 
95.11, 78.48, 67.18, 64.66, NA, 92.9, 87.99, 73.26, 63.18, NA, 
93.46, 69.54, 78.46, 71.28, 70.2, 46.87, 60.01, 46.9, NA, 79.95, 
63.61, 76.41, 70.83, 70.56, 61.2, 63.99, 60.99, 58.88, 58.85, 
57.38, 54.8, 71.11, 67.89, 64.96, 70.99, 70.85, 58.38, 53.94, 
58.56, 56.88, 53.38, 47.07, 51.52, 44.38, NA, 86.63, 77.56, NA, 
86.6, 82.69, 84.51, 72.96, 85.48, 81.32, 75.96, 65.32, NA, 98.61, 
113.09, 86.35, NA, 111.09, 100.43, NA, 107.09, 105.11, 76.3, 
96.49, 81.72, NA)), row.names = c(38819L, 35876L, 32913L, 28959L, 
27969L, 24993L, 22013L, 19023L, 15022L, 13008L, 8983L, 6986L, 
3003L, 38411L, 36285L, 32500L, 29370L, 28382L, 24579L, 22430L, 
18606L, 15443L, 12587L, 9399L, 6570L, 3418L, 38818L, 35877L, 
32912L, 28960L, 27970L, 24992L, 22014L, 19022L, 15023L, 13007L, 
8984L, 6985L, 3004L, 38815L, 35880L, 32909L, 28963L, 27973L, 
24989L, 22017L, 19019L, 15026L, 13004L, 8987L, 6982L, 3007L, 
38469L, 35976L, 32798L, 29056L, 28066L, 24881L, 22109L, 18905L, 
15118L, 12886L, 9076L, 6865L, 3099L, 38794L, 35901L, 32888L, 
28984L, 27994L, 24968L, 22038L, 18997L, 15048L, 12982L, 9009L, 
6960L, 3029L, 38775L, 35920L, 32869L, 29002L, 28012L, 24950L, 
22056L, 18980L, 15065L, 12965L, 9025L, 6944L, 3047L, 38774L, 
35921L, 32868L, 29003L, 28013L, 24949L, 22057L, 18979L, 15066L, 
12964L, 9026L, 6943L, 3048L, 38769L, 35926L, 32863L, 29008L, 
28018L, 24944L, 22062L, 18974L, 15071L, 12959L, 9031L, 6938L, 
3053L, 38764L, 35931L, 32858L, 29013L, 28023L, 24939L, 22067L, 
18969L, 15076L, 12954L, 9035L, 6934L, 3057L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution, based on duplicating the rows where the current direction of yield changes.

```r
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

# Set five_year_display as data.table
setDT(five_year_display)


#Order the five year display, and create an row identifier
five_year_display[order(Animal_ID, Date),rowid:=.I]

# Create a version that duplicates rows when the next row changes direction
fyd <- rbindlist(list(
  five_year_display, 
  five_year_display[five_year_display[,dup_row:=sign(Yeild-shift(Yeild,-1))!=sign(shift(Yeild,1)-Yeild), by = Animal_ID][dup_row==TRUE, rowid]]
),idcol = "src")[order(Animal_ID, Date, src)]

# Function to set the colors, based on yield and rowid
# This function first finds the initial direction of the yield,
# sets the color for that direction, and then
# looks at the changes in row id to determine toggle in colors
find_colors <- function(yield, rowid) {
  colors=as.numeric(yield[1]>=yield[2])
  for(i in seq(2,length(rowid))) {
    if(rowid[i]>rowid[i-1]) colors = c(colors, colors[i-1])
    else colors = c(colors, 1-colors[i-1])
  }
  return(colors)
}

# Use function above to assign colors to each row
fyd[,colors:=find_colors(Yeild,rowid), by=Animal_ID]

# create a colorgrp over animal and color, using rleid
fyd[,colorgrp:=rleid(Animal_ID,colors)]

# plot the fyd using the colorgrp in geom_line, and manually setting the color scale
ggplot(fyd, aes(as.Date(Date), Yeild)) + 
  geom_point()+
  geom_line(aes(group=colorgrp,color=factor(colors, labels=c("Increasing", "Decreasing")))) + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("green", "red")) + 
  labs(x = "Date", color="Slope") + 
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

Here is the resulting plot

[image: slopes with colors]